# Write an Array (of real) to an Siemens 1500 with OPC UA on WINDEV

Tags: opc-ua, siemens, windev

(sorry for my french way to write english)

Hi,
After many research on net and doc, i can't resolve my problem

I try to write an array of 150 real to siemens with OPC UA :

```
PROCÉDURE WriteArrayToNode(NodeIdTxt is string)

Trace("lets write")


myNodeId        is NodeId(gsNotreBD+"."+NodeIdTxt)
nodesToWrite    is WriteValueCollection <- new WriteValueCollection()
nodeToWrite     is WriteValue           <- new WriteValue()
nodeToWrite.NodeId                  = myNodeId
nodeToWrite.AttributeId             = Attributes.Value

Trace(Attributes.ValueRank,Attributes.Value,Attributes.ArrayDimensions)

vTemp is Opc.Ua.variant(gTab_W_PARA)   //gTab_W_PARA is the array of 150 real i trying to write
clDataValue1 is DataValue <- new DataValue(vTemp);

nodeToWrite.Value=clDataValue1
nodeToWrite.IndexRange="1:150"

nodesToWrite.Add(nodeToWrite);

clRequestHeader is RequestHeader <- new RequestHeader()
myResults is StatusCodeCollection dynamic = new StatusCodeCollection
myDiagsInfo is DiagnosticInfoCollection dynamic = new DiagnosticInfoCollection
request is RequestHeader dynamic =  new RequestHeader

gmySession.Write(request,nodesToWrite,myResults,myDiagsInfo)

Trace(myDiagsInfo.get_Count())

Trace("scribe ? ")
RETURN True
Trace(" yes scribe ")

CASE ERROR:
Trace("erreur",ExceptionInfo)
RETURN False
CASE EXCEPTION:
Trace("exception",ExceptionInfo)
RETURN False
```

The TRACE give :

```
lets write      //start of process
15 13 16        // Attributes.ValueRank,Attributes.Value,Attributes.ArrayDimensions  I don't understand :
                // With doc, I admit it say Attributes is 15 dimensional array with value of 13 ? and 16 
                // index,  but who is Attributes ? I never use array like that
0               
scribe ?        //it return true, so there is no error ?
```

But in siemens my array don't change, so the write not work ?
i try use variant and Datavalue like in many example, but i not sure its the good way.
if someone can help I thank him in advance

Answer (score 0):

Probably your using of IndexRange is wrong.

Assuming that you only use an OneDimensional S7 Array REAL[1..150] (which the dataVariable indicates whith Attributes ValueRank and ArrayDimensions)

Do not use S7 ranges syntax with OPC UA IndexRange!

1. From the UA Spec:

"All indexes start with 0. The maximum value for any index is one less than the length of the dimension."

So "1:150" adresses a range, that doesn't exists on the server. "0:149" would be correct.

2. If you address the whole array, don't use an IndexRange at all. In fact, this will have some performance issues on servers.
3. Maybe S7-1500 OPC Server does not support IndexRange at all, when writing. But it should return an error.